# How to Mock HttpClientBuilder for Unit Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, http, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test for the http post implementation. However I'm unable to mock the httpclient properly and my when statement is never getting triggered. The unit test I have written is making an actual http call instead of responding with a mock response. 
How do we proceed with mocking a client created by HttpClientBuilder?

**Http Method Implementation:**

```
HttpResponse postRequest(String url, String request) {
    HttpResponse resp = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(request));

        resp = client.execute(post);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Test Method:**

```
@Mock
private HttpClient httpClient;

when(httpClient.execute(any())).thenReturn(httpResponse);
```

Comment: can you post the entire class `postRequest` is in, alongside the full test class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do we proceed with mocking a client created by HttpClientBuilder?

**We don't!!!**

Try to avoid mocking 3rd party concerns

Create an abstraction of the tightly coupled static implementation concern

```
public interface HttpClientFactory {
    public HttpClient create();
}
```

With a simple implementation that will be used in production.

```
public class HttpClientFactoryImpl implements HttpClientFactory {

    //...

    public HttpClient create() {
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
    }

    //...
}
```

Using Dependency Inversion, the encapsulating class should explicitly depend on the abstraction to avoid violating Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)

```
public class SystemUnderTest {

    private HttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

    public SystemUnderTest(HttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    HttpResponse postRequest(String url, String request) {
        HttpResponse resp = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.create();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(request));

            resp = client.execute(post);
            return resp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This Separation of Concerns (SoC) allows it *(your encapsulating class)* to be more flexible to unit test in isolation.

```
@Test
public void testPostRequest() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    HttpResponse expected = mock(HttpResponse.class);
    HttpClient httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class);
    when(httpClient.execute(any())).thenReturn(expected);

    HttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = mock(HttpClientFactory.class);
    when(httpClientFactory.create()).thenReturn(httpClient);

    SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest(httpClientFactory);

    String url = "http://url_here";
    String request = "Hello World";

    // Act
    HttpResponse actual = systemUnderTest.postRequest(url, request);

    // Assert
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
    //should also verify that the expected arguments as passed to execute()
}
```